# Add padding between images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add a space (white space) between images in a bootstrap div.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/img4.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
```

If I add `style="margin: 2px;"` it pushes the last image to outside the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap3 `col-*` classes have `padding:15px` already. So I think there is no need to add extra space.

But if you want to add more spacing(`padding` or `margin`) between images try to wrap the images into another div and then use `margin` or `padding` values to that div....or apply padding or margin in image itself...you will get the result.

Now `margin:2px` pushes the last image to the next line because currently your `col` have width `25%` i.e. width `(25*4=100%)` of the row...if you apply `margin:2px` to the `col`, the width of the `col` will be `25%+2px` resulting the `100%+8px` to the whole row because ***margin is always applied to outside the box and padding is applied to inside***...thats why your last `col` is pushed to next line....

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  /* put your padding here */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recomened not to add padding in grid element. Bootstrap grid have own padding. Use figure element isnted like this

```
<div class="images row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <figure><img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></figure>
</div>
</div>
```

and styles

```
.images figure {
    padding: 10px;
    /* display: block; */
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo url : https://output.jsbin.com/jejeho

Answer (score 1):

Use nested columns, this will create spaces between images by default

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example with placeholder images

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXOaev?page=1&

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Set the padding of parent div.

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding:10px;">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
```